# The button in nattable is covering half of my table, can someone explain why?

Tags: button, nattable

i have used the following code for the button

```
natTable.addOverlayPainter(new NatTableBorderOverlayPainter());
  Composite panel = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
  GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
  layout.marginHeight = 5;
  layout.marginWidth = 8;
  panel.setLayout(layout);
  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(panel);
  Composite gridPanel = new Composite(panel, SWT.NONE);
  gridPanel.setLayout(layout);
  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, true).applyTo(gridPanel);

  Composite buttonPanel = new Composite(panel, SWT.NONE);
  buttonPanel.setLayout(new RowLayout());
  GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().grab(true, false).applyTo(buttonPanel);

  Button addButton = new Button(gridPanel, SWT.PUSH);
  addButton.setText("Export");
  addButton.setSize(1, 1);
  addButton.setLocation(450, 150);
  addButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
          natTable.doCommand(new ExportCommand(natTable
                  .getConfigRegistry(), null, editable));
          natTable.updateResize();
      }
```

but at the end i am getting this as a result
[https://imgur.com/EFcPaqo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qub95.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is broken. Probably because the NatTable instance is not created on one of your Composites. But hard to tell without seeing the creation of it.

Either have a look at [Understanding layouts in SWT](https://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) or even check the NatTable examples [PrintExample](https://github.com/eclipse/nebula.widgets.nattable/blob/master/org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.examples/src/org/eclipse/nebula/widgets/nattable/examples/_700_AdditionalFunctions/_761_PrintExample.java) that shows exactly the same. There you can see that NatTable is created on the `gridPanel`.

Comment: Hello Dirk, thanks for your reply, my nattable instance is created like that (in the image attached, the composite is parent , we haven't changed it https://imgur.com/a/9eDJd2O

Comment: Why do you then expect anything else as what you see? IIRC the default layout in the parent shell is a RowLayout or even no layout at all.